# Activity on top of mapview

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-mapview

I have a `Activity` on top of a `MapView` that only covers a small portion at the top to display additional data.This Activity is called when a `Polygon` is touched on the map. The issue that I am faced with is that the first activity gets disable when the second Activity is in view. Is there a way to still interact with the first activity when the second one is being displayed? Or is there a better way of accomplishing what I am trying to achieve which is displaying a custom view at the top of the `MapView`. Thanks

Comment: You should take a look on `DialogFragment`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html. Or `PopupWindow`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html. Or if a Dialog isn't what you're after, please explain what will the "custom view at the top" contain.

Comment: You should take a look at Fragments and not DialogFragment as mentioned above. also you should notice the difference between Activities and Views (these are not the same, or can't be placed on top of). A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. In your case you will have 2 fragments one being a fragment holding the mapview, the other will be "additional data"

Comment: If you want to interact with the MapView and the newly created view at the same time, then it's true, DIalogFragment isn't the best option. I just can't think of a usage pattern for such a behaviour. Aren't you trying to implement Map Bubbles (InfoWindows)?

Comment: The data that is in the custom view is specific data about the polygon that was touched. I have an intent that sends the data to the second activity. The second activity parses the data and displays it over the MapView.

Comment: Another suggestion is using one activity holding a relative layout, With a relative layout you can stack views (create the illusion one is in front of another) so you could have a viewgroup holding addiontional data + having you mapview "under" it. Also this cannot be done using 2 activities...

Comment: Wouldn't this suffice? https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons Or if you use Map API v2, there are InfoWindows for something like this

Comment: The reason this is needed is a user may not want to hit the close button on the second view to look at the data attached to the next polygon.

Comment: Well, it looks like all you need is a `RelativeLayout` and some Layout placed over the MapView. OnClick update this Layout with appropriate data. That's all, no additional activity or Dialog or anything needed.

Comment: Michal K, You rock!! I was over doing it this works perfectly

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped :)